# MPMusicPlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, mpmusicplayercontroller

The call to setCurrentPlaybackRate to the MPMusicPlayerController stopped working after the latest iOS update, and now gives this error:

```
2018-04-15 16:24:06.904562-0600 SampleProject[5659:1836398] [SDKPlayback] -
[MPMusicPlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.670213] completed error: 
Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "No commands provided." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No commands provided.}
```

I'm passing in a valid double value greater than 0 and less than 2.

This is the call:
[appMusicPlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.7];

Thanks for any input or help!

P.S. I'm getting a lot of other weird errors too. Here are some:

```
2018-04-15 17:30:01.976932-0600 SampleProject[5733:1868672] [SDKPlayback] 
Failed validators: {(
     setRepeatMode
)}
2018-04-15 17:30:03.976879-0600 SampleProject[5733:1868672] [SDKPlayback] 
Failed to get a valid response. Resetting expectations.

2018-04-15 17:30:01.976932-0600 SampleProject[5733:1868672] [SDKPlayback] 
Failed validators: {(
    setRepeatMode
)}
2018-04-15 17:30:03.976879-0600 SampleProject[5733:1868672] [SDKPlayback] 
Failed to get a valid response. Resetting expectations.
```

Comment: I've never heard of setting the playback rate on an MPMusicPlayerController (such that it is anything but zero or one). Did this previously work?

Comment: Yes it did previously work, and it was glorious.

Comment: I had no idea! This sounds to me like grounds for you to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Submitted a bug to Apple

Comment: Try to add a delay after set

Comment: @yebw that is a really good suggestion! thanks

Comment: @TheJeff did you figure it out, i am getting the same errors and i dont know what am i doing wrong. going by the textbook

Comment: I've filed a bug to Apple, and they are asking for a sample app to troubleshoot the problem. I gave them one, but it has an issue - the MPMediaPickerController immediately dismisses, so I'm a bit blocked on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469928/mpmediapicker-does-not-show

I ended up switching to AVPlayer which works great most of the time, however there is another bug with that where the assetUrl is sometimes nil, so I can't play some songs at all. I logged this in the bug reporter and am working with Apple to have them fix that as well. @UsamabinAttique

Comment: Functionality seems to have improved, however the weird logs are still there. The logs don't seem to be associated with the player malfunctioning anymore from what I see. Another thing I've noticed are some odd threading issues. Observing the state of the media player from the same thread you start a task on is inconsistent. I recommend asynchronously kicking off your player mutations (play,stop,pause,etc), that way when you're checking player state, the checks are coming from a different thread and are much more likely to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue when trying to use `player.append(MPMusicPlayerQueueDescriptor)`. I found that it would return the same error when the queue for my `MPMusicPlayerController` was quite large. When I cut it down to around 10, it works with no issues. I haven't experimented to see the maximum I can add to the queue.

I hope this helps, perhaps a smaller queue will also work for you.

Comment: My queue size is 1