# MPMediaPicker does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

In a sample app that I'm making for Apple, I cannot get the MPMediaPickerController to show.

I've already added the NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key in the info.plist file, and this is what makes my post different from any other answers found online.

I've also tried adding CoreMedia.framework.

I'm using XCode 10 beta 4

The app never asks for permissions to access the media library, and when I present the picker, the mediaPickerDidCancel method is called right away.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaPickerController.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Objc file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)selectButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    [picker setDelegate: self];
    [picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems: NO];
    picker.prompt = @"Select a Song.";

    UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    [rootController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Complete!");
    }];
}

- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) collection {

    MPMediaItem *firstItem;
    for (MPMediaItem *item in collection.items) {
        firstItem = item;
        break;
    }

    MPMusicPlayerController *samplePlayer  = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [samplePlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
    [samplePlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeOne];
    [samplePlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];

    // self.mediaItem chosen using MPMediaPickerController
    [samplePlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:@[firstItem]]];
    [samplePlayer prepareToPlay];

    // Assume that song is at least 120 seconds long
    [samplePlayer play];
}

#pragma mark - delegate methods and segues

- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you running on sim or device?

Comment: I'm confused why `// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.` is found in your IBAction method; that's typically a note seen in viewDidLoad method. I only point this out because if you are trying to access rootViewController in viewDidLoad it won't work as the keyWindow won't have rendered yet; but in your code this is done in IBAction so it would work, but if this code you've posted is not identical to your code and it is actually in viewDidLoad not IBAction that could be the issue.

Comment: That comment auto-populates when connecting an action method from the Interface Builder. This is the actual code I'm running and it doesn't differ from the sample app I made. @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: Interesting!! This is a really baffling issue then!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, was it ever resolved?

Comment: No, however I have a theory that its because the app isn't registered in app store connect / dev portal correctly and may have something to do with provisioning. I made it most of the way towards testing this theory and didn't finish up. Let me know if this solves your issue - verifying provisioning.